# Image does not display in report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

My asp.net app has a report which displays information about a given football player. When I try to display the table data on the asp.net page, the photo doesn't display even though the rest of the information does. How can I make the image display correctly?

I store the photo as a `byte[]..` and on dataset I fill the report. I also added a field called `Photo` with type of `System.Byte[]`.

[image: Section 2]

I dragged and dropped the object into from my app:

[image]

I know I'm not sending empty data because the array of bytes is clearly in my database and it returns a whole object.

[image]

```
public partial class PlayersReport : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
      var x = Server.MapPath("~");

      int playerID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["playerID"]);
      PlayersDataSet players = new PlayersDataSet();
      PlayersDataSet.PlayersTableDataTable PlayersDT = new PlayersDataSet.PlayersTableDataTable();
      var player = eSavez_Servis.Data.Services.DAPlayers.GetByPlayerId(playerID);

      PlayersDT.AddIgraciTableRow(player.FirstName, player.LastName, player.ClubNumber, player.ClubName, player.Photo, player.IDNumber.ToString());

      players.Tables["PlayersTable"].Merge(PlayersDT);

      rpt_Players RPT = new rpt_Players();
      RPT.SetDataSource(players);
      CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPT;

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help mate, I appreciate that, I solved error last night and problem was very dumb, in the field on report that I drag and drop from DataTable attribute called Photo did not changed to system.byte[] even if I changed it on dataTable from my dataTableSet, somehow it did not refresh and it stayed still as a string so my image couldn't load on field of type string, so I removed DataTable from Database Fields(Database expert) and move it back, and dragged fields again to report and everything went fine!

:)

Comment: Yes, and thank you again for your effort, hope that we will stay in touch and hope that I will see you around :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope  this can help you : 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-image-from-database-in-Crystal-Report-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

So use a DataTable to bind your report, in case your db's pictures are not stored properly and CR cannot bind them.

EDIT : 
Hum, i just see that you set your photo attribute in the pageheader so it cannot work ! Move it to the DetailSection with the other attribute of your class and in the PageHeader just add a text field with "Photo" written.

SECOND EDIT :
I have several questions to help you : Did you set breakpoint to see the data in your DataTable/dataSet before the CR load ? And precisely the dataType and data.
Do you see the image in the preview ?
Did you check your image encoding in database ? The problem could be just here, the encoding data is not correctly interpreted by CR. I googled this problem for you and all the problems i saw was the encoding in db or decoding part.

Did you try with a DataBind ?

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPT;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
```

In your edited code behind i don't understand what you do here, why not a select * from your db directly in your dataset ? Why store in `var player` ? the data type could go wrong here and your image couldn't be load because of that.

Comment: I checked that link before, and I was wondering what is happening because I did almost the same as the guy who wrote that post, and interesting part is that for example my object has 5 attributes, Name, Last Name, ID, Photo etc.. and all of them are displayed on report just photo is missing, and my photo is stored in database table just like other attributes and I really don't know why it doesn't displaying :/

Comment: But did  you test it with a DataTable instead of directly drag and drop your data ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "did you test it with a DataTable"?

Comment: I mean did you test it like the link i posted ? Use a DataTable to bind your report values instead of drag and drop directly from your db. Use a DataTable between your db and CR to be sure to stored properly your pictures.

Comment: Yes I did it, I will post screenshoot later, I am not home right now, soon I will be home and I will post screenshoot about that so you can see closer :)

Comment: Okay np, a last advice, post your db table here, so we can see the type of your columns . Maybe it's a db problem !

Comment: Its allready in details all of the attributes, I just took screenshoot of page header :)

Comment: You cannot change the type of your picture column to image type ? Or test with this type instead of byte ?

Comment: I dont know how to do it right now, is it possible? Ussualy I Am storing images to my databse as a array of bytes, and when I'm creating dataTable I just set propertie of a field that I want to display image to System.Byte[] and I thought everything will be fine :/ .. but anyway  I will check your suggestion if it is possible as soon as I arrive home